# Xcode App validation Loss of Key-chain access warning

Tags: ios, xcode

I am preparing to submit an update to an app that has been on the app store for a couple of years. I have since created new certificates and profiles. When I validate, I get a warning message saying the app indentity entitlement has changed resulting in a loss of key-chain access. I have not changed the bundle identifier. My app uses the keychain to store a username and password to validate an in-app purchase. I take it that the app will no longer be able to access this keychain item thus the app will not reconize the in-app purchase.
If I have the user execute the Restore Purchases function, will they be charged again for the in-app or will ITunes still reconize the previous purchase? What determines this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purchase is registered against their iTunes account.  As long as they restore using the same iTunes account that they originally used (and assuming that it is a non-consumable purchase) then their purchase will be restored at no cost.

Comment: I created a new Distribution profile using a Wildcard app ID. The app now passes Validation with no warnings. Does this mean the in-app purchase will still work correctly in the new updated version and that new users will still be able make the In-App purchase?

Comment: I am getting this error and the wildcard ID didn't help. I'm about to submit to the App Store in spite of the warning and hope it all works out. :)